# Circular view path [index.jsp]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/index.jsp] again

Tags: spring-mvc

It's My Project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoixU.png)

It's My spring-mvc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.SpringDemo.Controller"/>
 <!-- Thymeleaf Template Resolver -->
    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
      <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
      <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
      <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
      <property name="enableSpringELCompiler" value="true" />
    </bean>

  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
      <property name="viewNames" value="thymeleaf/*"/>
      <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean>

  <!-- 对模型视图名称的解析，即在模型视图名称添加前后缀 -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />

      <property name="prefix" value="" />
      <!--<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />-->
      <property name="order" value="2" />
      <property name="viewNames" value="*.jsp" />
    </bean>
<!-- 支持上传文件 -->
  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
</beans>
```

It's My Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController{
  //It's OK
   @RequestMapping("/home")
   public String showHomePage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("name","spring-mvc");
        return "thymeleaf/testTh";
   }
  //It's WRONG
   @RequestMapping("/index")
   public ModelAndView test(ModelAndView mv){
      mv.addObject("name","erer");
      mv.setViewName("index.jsp");
      return  mv;
   }
}
```

It's My Exception

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Bbbd.png)

In's My Web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <!-- 加载springMVC的配置文件 -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want that all requests are first passed through the controller.
And then return to the page

Answer (score 5):

Please import spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf

```
<dependency>            
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

I think the problems may be located on the returned view name. Since the view name is the same as the /index path, so maybe it will be dispatched by spring dispatcher again. Maybe you can try to change the view as another name to have a try.

Comment: Thank You.Now,I use spring boot .

Comment: Seriously! life saver comment :-) This is the nonsense error with spring. Really worried to bet my project on these kinds of idiotic framework.